# Выражение неизвестной через цикл на python

Tags: python

Определите, при каком наибольшем введённом значении переменной s
программа выведет число 64. Для Вашего удобства программа представлена
на четырёх языках программирования. Демо егэ по информатике.

```
s = int(input())
s = s // 10
n = 1
while s < 51:
    s = s + 5
    n = n * 2
print(n)
```

Как реализовать программу через поиск `s`, приняв `n` за известную?

Мои попытки:

1.

```
s = 50
n = 64
while n != 1:
    s -=5
    n /= 2
print(s)
```

2. 

```
s = 20
n = 1
while s < 51:
    s = s + 5
    n = n * 2
print(s)
```

Comment: простите не в тему. на каких 4х языках щас еге сдают ?  #ответ на задачу 259 ?

Comment: что-то не вижу я тут 4х языков...

Comment: @Интик python, C++, Паскаль и алгоритмический. Да, 259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поскольку ограничения по времени нет, то попробуем перебором через цикл:

```
def foo(s):
    #s = int(input())   
    s = s // 10
    n = 1
    while s < 51:
        s = s + 5
        n = n * 2
    if n==64:return 64    
    
m=0
for i in range (0,519+1):
    if foo(i)==64:
        m=i
        
print('наибольшее число:',m)
```

даны расчёты, их оформляем как функцию.инпут заменяет аргумент функции.
далее простым циклом от 0 до 519 перебирвем варианты. m=i без проверки что m больше чем предыдущая изза цикла-он идёт всегда по возрастанию и последнее i будет максимальным.

```
for i in range (519,8,-1):
    if foo(i)==64:
        m=i
        break
```

немного оптимизации, как подсказали в комментарии-пустить цикл в обратном направлении.при нахождении ответа сразу завершаем.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
from math import log

n = 64
mult_n = 2 # на сколько умножаем n
max_s = 51-1 # s < 51
step_s = 5 # s = s + 5

p = int(log(n, mult_n))
print((max_s-step_s*(p-1))*10+9)
```

Для экономии времени при больших `n` имеет смысл вывод сделать так:

```
print(f'{max_s-step_s*(p-1)}9')
```

Без модуля `math`:

```
def log(x, y):
    r, c = 1, 0
    while r!=x:
        r *= y
        c += 1
    return c
```

```
def check(s):
    s //= 10
    n = 1
    while s < 51:
        s += 5
        n *= 2
    return n==64 
    
for i in range(519, -1, -1):
    if check(i):
        break
        
print(f'Наибольшее s: {i}')
```

Comment: простите, но в дано s = s // 10  и макс s не 51,а 519

Comment: @Интик исправил вывод. спасибо

Comment: @n1tr0xs Спасибо. А без math не получится реализовать?

Comment: @pointDeceit разве что написать самому функцию логарифма. или циклом делать поиск (не советую)

Comment: @pointDeceit добавил простую реализацию `log`.